# Why didn't Orihime use her powers to reject the creation of the Espada?

Tags: bleach

I finished the Hueco Mundo arc, up to episode 190, and I have a question about Orihime:

If Orihime can reject all things, why didn't she reject Aizen's creation of the Espadas? She can just say "I reject" and then cast at the Espada. POOF, gone.

Comment: Maybe she can only reject things up to a 'certain level'? (and needs (more) training to increase this level)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because her power is limited.

Rejecting the Espada's creation would mean *changing very powerful things*, beings with extreme spiritual power would vanish.

*She doesn't (yet) have this kind of power*. She can't reject events of that magnitude.

She can reject **an injury** (and even that to some degree, as shown with Ichigo's cero-inflicted wound by Ulquiorra, she couldn't reject such a powerful event), and she can **reject incoming attacks** (again, to some degree. Yami in his weak form was able to break it with his finger).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Orihime has the single most gamebreaking power in the story by being able to reject reality. The thing is, she´s also a pacifist medic, intentionally made so by Kubo to make it so there´s actually a plot. Why would you even write a story if a secondary character could kill every character in 1 second? You wouldn´t right? If she had the will and bloodlust to hurt others she could just go around deleting villains.

Comment: Maybe after the series ends, someone can write an alternate arc, "If Orihime was a sociopath."